# Creating and populating a table with foreign keys using InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an InnoDB table that lists customer orders - this table records the customer's email address, contact information for the order, and the order id. This table uses innodb and contains roughly 220 million rows. What I do not have, is a table that lists the users.

Is it possible, perhaps using foreign keys, for me to create and populate a table that will contain a `customer_id` and `e-mail` address from the data that is in my orders table?

This is the query that I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO customers (email, last_order) 
  SELECT (email_address, order_date) FROM orders 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE last_order = MAX(order_date, last_order);
```

I believe this query will build the database, but it won't put the customer id into the row in the orders table, and I am not sure if it is the best approach to start with. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it does not fail, looks good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this it in 2 steps:

1st, fill in the `customers` table:

```
INSERT INTO customers (email, last_order ) SELECT email_address, 
max(order_date) as last_order FROM orders GROUP by email_address;
```

2nd, update the `orders` table with customers' ids (assuming you have a field called `customer_id` in the `orders` table)

```
UPDATE orders o SET customer_id = 
    (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE email = o.email_address);
```

Finally, if you want to keep your `customers` table consistent, you can add an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` to the `orders` table to keep your `customers` table up-to-date.